# Python how to iterate over StrEnum without linter (PyCharm inspections) unresolved references

Tags: python, enums, pycharm, static-analysis

I have implemented a `StrEnum` (aka enforcing `Enum` members to be `str`) per the instructions within the Python 3.6 `enum` docs, section [`8.13.13.4 Others`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/enum.html#others).

```py
from enum import Enum


class StrEnum(str, Enum):
    """Enum where members are strings."""
```

I have a subclass of `StrEnum` where I use a `for` loop to iterate through it.

```py
class TestStrEnum(StrEnum):
    """Test string enum."""

    A = "Apple"
    B = "Bananas"


for enum_ in TestStrEnum:
    print(f"name = {enum_.name}, value = {enum_.value}.")
```

This works fine at runtime.  However, my linter complains about an unresolved reference when referring to the `name` and `value` attributes:

[image: Pycharm unresolved reference on enum]

**How can I get my linter to not complain?**

The problem seems to be that the linter is not properly inspecting within the `StrEnum._member_map_`.  I think the solution may be to override a dunder method within `StrEnum`, but am not sure which one to use.

---

**Workaround Solution**

Here is a workaround I figured out by using the `__members__` attribute to access the members in an explicit manner.

```py
for enum_member_name, enum_member in TestStrEnum.__members__.items():
    print(f"name = {enum_member.name}, value = {enum_member.value}.")
```

---

My linter is `PyCharm 2019.2.6 CE`'s code inspections.

****EDIT****

Per @user2235698's answer, it seems this is a known issue with PyCharm: [PY-36205](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36205), raised in May 2019.  Since this issue only currently has 6 upvotes (as of April 11th, 2020), I am not sure it will be fixed anytime soon.

If anyone has a good solution that can be used until the issue is resolved, I am still interested.

Comment: Have you tried adding a class level type hint to `StrEnum`, e.g. `name: str` in the class body?

Comment: Hi @Brian yes I tried that, and it does not work.  I think the real problem is my linter is using the enum's `_member_type_`.  For a `StrEnum`, the `_member_type` is a `str` as opposed to `object`.

Comment: Just updated the question with more information on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is a known issue, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36205 (thumbs up near the issue title)

Comment: Thank you @user2235698, I just gave it a thumbs up and linked this question